# Angular2 http withCredentials doesn't work

Tags: angular, cookies, angular2-http

I am using Angular2 http module to send http request. After user login, backend server will generate a cookie session and frontend will send request with this credentials. Below is the angular code:

```
get(url: string) {
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.get(url, options)
  }
```

It works fine with I launch my backend server in local environment. But it doesn't work if I connect to the remote backend server on AWS. 
From chrome network panel, I can see below data in request header when I connect my local server:

```
Cookie:doxygen_width=256; grafana_sess=029b64eee4853; mongo-express=s%3AeTrefMEC2AOUe5evI0LWmQzTZcgsb.n2tP7es2RtWYfNN6lhg8ZXXAc%2FAdvswTnYBlrEhgTgM; session_id=f64d1718e54ad0a0c0bccdf782d91d; _ga=GA1.1.753746608.1498715254; linkedin_oauth_75nvlf2kt3yji2_crc=null
```

but when I connect to the remote server I couldn't see this cookie header in the request. I also checked login response data which has session data there. I am confused that with same angularjs code why it doesn't work for remote server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
get(url: string) {
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.get(url,{ headers: headers, search: params })
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the `options` here. It seems that no one uses the options.